# How to blur the BottomNavigationBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to blur the background of BottomNavigationBar of a scaffold, so that it can give cool blur effect of items behind it. How can I do that?

**More Info:** I've tried adding opacity to canvasColor by creating a new theme to the BottomNaviagtionBar. This is my code:

`bottomNavigationBar: new Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
       canvasColor: Color(0xff424242).withOpacity(0.5),
    ),
    child: new BottomNavigationBar(
       onTap: navigationTapped,
       currentIndex: _page,
       items: [
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
            title: new Text('Home')
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.dashboard),
            title: new Text('Menu')
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.date_range),
            title: new Text('Dates')
          )
        ],
    ),
  )`

And this is output I'm getting:[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvtgS.jpg)

Surprisingly, as you can see, the opacity is not at all applied. I actually don't want the BottomNavigationBar to be opaque. I want it to be blurred so that the content behind it can be viewed as blurred on the BottomNaviagtionBar. I've tried also to wrap BottomNavigationBar inside ImageFilter.blur(), But that also didn't work.

Comment: Can you please share some more details like any reference image or code that you have tried till now?

Comment: you want to blur the background of the BottomNavigationBar or the foreground?

Comment: I've added more info. please check

Comment: I want to blur the background

Comment: I tried the ImageFilter.blur() and it worked, but BottomNavigationBar has a shadow inside that hides the blur and the blur is bigger than the BottomNavigationBar. Will try to make it work.

Comment: Thank you. Please post the code if it works.

Answer (score 10):

For this to work I had to place the bottom navigation in a stack with the other content of the screen. I used combination of ClipRect, BackdropFilter and Opacity. This is the working solution:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _buildAppBar(context),
      body: Stack(
        //these are the screens that will be loaded for every bottom nav item
        children: <Widget>[
          IndexedStack(
            index: _currentTab,
            children: _pages,
          ),
          _buildBottomNavigation()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

Widget _buildBottomNavigation() => Align(
        alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
        //this is very important, without it the whole screen will be blurred
        child: ClipRect(
          //I'm using BackdropFilter for the blurring effect
          child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(
              sigmaX: 10.0,
              sigmaY: 10.0,
            ),
            child: Opacity(
              //you can change the opacity to whatever suits you best
              opacity: 0.8,
              child: BottomNavigationBar(
                currentIndex: _currentTab,
                onTap: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    _currentTab = index;
                  });
                },
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                unselectedItemColor: AppColors.colorBlack,
                items: allRoutes.map((NavigationRoute route) {
                  return _buildBottomNavigationBarItem(route);
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: Note: avoid helper methods that return Widgets. Create a new Widget instead for a performance improvement.

Answer (score 5):

You could just wrap your BottomNavigationBar with a Backdropfilter and then wrap all with a ClipRRect. Last but not least set the Scaffold attribute extendBody to true,

```
 bottomNavigationBar: ClipRRect(
    child: BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3, sigmaY: 3),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
       YOUR CODE HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
** just set a transparent backgroundColor .**
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        border: Border.all(
          width: 0.0,
          style: BorderStyle.none,
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 20.0,
                    top: 0.0,
                    right: 20.0,
                  ),
                  height: 280.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: Const.color.linearColors,
                    ),
//                    image: DecorationImage(
//                      image: AssetImage('assets/image/bac.png'),
//                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[Text('Hello')],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              /// end of Expanded
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Shows on top instead and alignment doesn't seem to work