# I want to make my bottomNavBar transparent

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview

I want to make my Bottom Nav Bar transparent, I have tried opacity with color property but it is not working. Just so you can have an idea im attaching a screenshot for better understanding

[image: screenshot]

kindly ignore the buttons on the nav bar, I just want the transparency, my code is following

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    .......
  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
    child: Text(
      'SUIVANT',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Karla', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thnx in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BottomNavigationBar Transparent Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126741/bottomnavigationbar-transparent-background)

Comment: can you add what exactly you want? do you want bottomNavigationBar transparent , so above listview (assuming) can visible behind ?

Comment: yes...that is exactly what I want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after a lot of thinking and applying odd ways I was able to do it in a very different way. I had to finish BottomNavigationBar: property since it doesnot allow to be modified. I had to wrap the main Column in Stack() widget

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          //.......
          /*this is the Container() I had to add in stack after finishing the bottomnavbar*/
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Text(
                    'SUIVANT',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Karla',
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

I don't know if it is a bad approach or the right one but I couldn't find a solution other than this after a lot of thought process. Do feel free to modify it according to the flutter rules if there are mistakes. Thanks everyone for contributing.

[This is how the result looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JGzK.png)

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what's the dev language you are using but i can tell you what to do in css side :

please in try add thiss background color code : #ffffff00 it should be like this in css

background-color :  #ffffff00

Comment: didn't work out, it shows yellow background after adding the color code, btw its Flutter(dart).

Comment: ok i dont know about flutter to be honoest, but  the code provided is for white transperant in css , sorry i couldn"t help

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the color of the **Container** to `Colors.transparent`

Like this

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Container(

      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Text("Bottom Nav is Transparent", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**UPDATE**

And if you want to use the **BottomNavigationBar** set the **elevation** to 0

For example

```
class Trans extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Container(

      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(title: Text("1",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),), icon: Icon(Icons.message)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(title: Text("2",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),), icon: Icon(Icons.message))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: bottomNavigationBar has the transparent color as solid white. doesn't help with Colors.transparent.

Comment: @FahadHussain I don't get you

Comment: doesn't help bro...it doesn't get transparent

Comment: What exactly do you mean Transparent Bottom Nav? You don't want the Bottom Nav Bar to show?